# Golang dlv debugger stopped working after intel mac 13.2 ventura upgrade

Tags: go, macos-ventura, dlv

Ever since I upgraded my intel mac to 13.2 Ventura, my golang debugger is no longer working.

go -> 1.18

dlv -> 1.20.1

When I try to attach to the go process, I am getting an error message as 'could not attach to pid 19474: stub exited while waiting for connection: exit status 0'

When I try to debug directly via dlv, it allows me to set my breakpoint, but the process never stops on that breakpoint.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I have re-installed command line tools, re-installed my goland IDE, and made sure that my dlv version is the latest.